# Efficiency of Finding Files with Perl

Tags: perl, find, glob

I'm trying to get an array of files from a directory tree in a Perl script. Sometimes I can grab them with glob expansion, but something I only way to capture what I need is with a regex.

For example, I might want to get all of the files which would match `verify/*.finished` with shell expansion. Using `glob(<pattern>)` is faster than matching everything found with `File::Find` when I know the depth at which the "verify" directory lives (e.g. `glob("*/*/*/verify/*.finished")`, but am a little stuck when I need to rely on regex matching.

Is there any way to get the efficiency of `glob` with the flexibility of regex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could just generate the full list of files with `glob`, then `grep` the results using regular expressions:

```
my @files = grep { /\.finished\z/ } glob '*/*/*/verify/*';
```

EDIT:

If the question is if there's a facility that works like glob but uses regular expressions, I believe the answer is no.  In the completely general case, I don't see that you have any alternative but to traverse an entire directory tree, and I doubt you'll be able to do substantially better than `File::Find`.

Comment: The problem is when I can't effectively glob. What the "verify" directory could live at many different depths? Sure, there might be a glob that could handle that, but what about any "*.finished" in the tree. I'm just concerned that I'm not doing it as efficient as possible when `glob(*/*/*/verify/*.finished)` is faster than File::Find and matching against `verify\/.*\.finished`.

Comment: @ajwood, whenever there are questions about the speed of one algorithm versus another, you should try [benchmarking](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) them, then iteratively fine tune to see if you can find faster ways. An alternate to globbing or File::Find would be to call the OS's `find` command. It's compiled and is very flexible so you could get a speed-up. You'll have to split lines when it returns, but that could be faster. Again, benchmarking will tell all.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easiest to just call the system find:

```
open(my $fh, "-|", find => ".", -type => "d", -name => "verify") or die "Err: $!";
while(<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  print "$_\n" for <$_/*.finished>;
}
close $fh or warn "Err: $!";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `File::Find` does under the hood. (Is it an XS module?) If it is reading the full contents of each directory and testing each entry individually with perl code, it might be faster to spawn a native `find` command. The relative efficiency of `glob` may be due to the fact that the inner loop is running in C rather than perl.

You may be able to optimize based on what you know about either your files or your search criteria. Using your example, a possibility might be breaking it into two steps:

1. search only for directories and look for anything with the exact name `"verify"`
2. look for `*.finished` in those directories

Comment: File::Find is not an XS module :-(

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
glob '{' . join( ',', map { join( '/', ('*') x $_ ) } (1..9) ) . '}/verify/*';
```

doesn't look like the performance is that good. Plus, if you have multiple `verify` directories, it will include them all.